# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int Msg 206, Level 16,State 2, Line #

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have this script that populates an export table

```
Insert Into Export_Table
Select '"'+
IsNull(Convert(int,ID),'')+@Delimit+
IsNull(Convert(int,CID),'')+@Delimit+
IsNull(Convert(varchar(1),NOT_USED_Staging_Completeness),'')+@Delimit+
IsNull(Convert(varchar(1),NOT_USED_C_Stage_Discussed),'')+@Delimit+
IsNull(Convert(varchar(1),NOT_USED_National_Guielines_Discussed),'')+@Delimit+
```

> IsNull(Convert(date,Screen_Date),'')+@Delimit+

```
IsNull(Convert(varchar(2),Screen_Date_Month),'')+'"'
From table
```

The line that is in quotes seems to be the one giving me issues. I have other tables as well and getting the same error. I know how to get past this if I were inserting a date, but here I'm trying to export the exact value of the date that is in that field. What do I need to change this to so that it will work and export the data?

Comment: What is @Delimit datatype and value?

Comment: that is just | character. It's for exporting purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to joint `Int` value with `String` `Convert(int,ID)+@Delimit` which is incorrect according to my knowledge

This should  `Convert(VARCHAR(30),ID)+@Delimit` this will convert your ID to string and this will allow to join `@Delimit` value. Pass proper length for `VARCHAR` .

Comment: That looks familiar from something I did last week. Let me try it this way and see if this works.

Comment: That worked! Thanks now I have another error but I'm pretty sure I can fix it.